# How to create multiple nodes in elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an elastic search in my application with single node,i need to create another node in my application.What is the query to create another node for my sample application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create several config files with difference in

```
# config/elasticsearch1.yml 
node.name=Node1
node.data=false 
node.master=true

# config/elasticsearch2.yml
node.name=Node2
node.data=true
node.master=false

# config/elasticsearch3.yml
node.name=Node3
node.data=true
node.master=false
```

Then, run several instances

```
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=/path/to/config/elasticsearch1.yml
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=/path/to/config/elasticsearch2.yml
$ bin/elasticsearch -Des.config=/path/to/config/elasticsearch3.yml
```

Comment: Thk u so much mikhail, sorry for my delayed reply